# PHP GD Image - use as as inline img src passing variables

Tags: php, html, gd

I have been spending 4 days for a genera issue. I am new to this stuff.

My general question is

```
<?php

$art = $_POST['source_file'];
$bag = $_POST['destination_file'];

$x1=100;
$y1 = 400;

$x2 = 700;
$y2 = 800;

?>

<img src = 'image.php'>

<?php
// other codes
?>
```

I need to pass $bag, $art, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2 to image.php and use it in creating GD image. If i used the values of the variables and stated in image.php, it works. If I used $a as is (i think the variable is global to image.php), it does not work.

If I replaced img src = 'image.php' with valid php require_once('image.php'), nothing is displayed in screen because the image is not created and because of header stated in image.php, the page behaves as an missed/not found image.

The content of Image.php is:

```
<?php

$bag=$_GET['bag'];
// this is the variable to be passed either by get or by post or by global variable

header ('Content-Type: image/png');

//$im = imagecreatefrompng('./bag_templates/bag1.PNG');
//this comented $im works. I need to pass content from variable

$im = imagecreatefrompng($bag);

//$source = imagecreatefromJPEG('./thumbnails/2014_12_10_23_53_48.JPG');
$source = imagecreatefromJPEG($art);
//$art variable must be passed from main page

list($source_width, $source_height)=getimagesize($art);

//variables x1,y1,x2,y2 must be passed from main file.
$frame_l = $x2-$x1;
$frame_h = $y2-$y1;

$start_x = $x1 + (($frame_l -$source_width)/2);
$start_y = $y1 + (($frame_h -$source_height)/2);

$destination = imagecreatefrompng($bag);

imagecopy($destination, $source, $start_x, $start_y, 0, 0, $source_width, $source_height); 
//bool imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )

imagepng($destination);
imagedestroy($destination);
?>
```

Variable that should be passed from the main file :

```
$bag
$art
$x1, $y1
$x2, $y2
```

The result of this image (merged image - $destination) should be displayed in main page - that simply calls image.php as -

```
img src ='image.php'
```

Comment: Hi, your goal is to simply pass the variables to image.php? Is that right? Sorry, I'm kinda confused on what you are attempting to do.    As you've mentioned, when you use require once image.php, the file is missing.   Plus you can't use a php as a src option.   Can you please give light to what image.php is?

Comment: You're referring to `$a`, `$b` and `$c`, which no longer exist in the current text

Comment: @olleh my understanding is that yes, that's the goal. And that they tried using `require_once('image.php')` instead of `<img src='image.php'>`, which obviously didn't display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your variables through a query string, passing them as key-value pairs and separating them with ampersands.

That means that instead of referring to `image.php` as is, you'll use `image.php?key1=value1&key2=value2&...`.

Although since this is HTML, you have to use `&amp;` instead of a plain `&`, e.g.:

```
<?php
// ...
echo "<img src='image.php?bag=$bag&amp;art=$art&amp;x1=$x1'>"
```

Then you can retrieve them from `image.php` by accessing the `$_GET` superglobal:

```
$bag = $_GET['bag'];
$art = $_GET['art'];
// and so on
```

---

If I understood correctly, you also tried to use something `require_once` instead of loading the image through `<img src='image.php'`. That would have the effect of dumping the image data into the HTML file directly, which won't render correctly (although it is *possible* to load images inline, I wouldn't recommend this approach).

Comment: using &amp; instead of & helped me. Is there any other way to pass the variables silently ? using like get structure makes it insecured when you have to pass full location due to scattered locations.

Comment: @ArjunPaudyal You could use e.g. [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to *pass* information between scripts, but it sounds like your design has some flaws. Looking at your code it seems like you're getting paths from `$_POST`(which is also insecure, just a bit less obvious). Instead, it would be better if the PHP *knew* where to look for the files and you only passed around the actual file name.